# jQuery Validation Plugin not work with Combodate

Tags: jquery, validation, combodate

I'm validating input fields with [jQuery Validaton Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).
There's a date input:

```
  <label for="date" class="label">Data di acquisto</label>
  <input id="date_xs" type="text" name="date" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-template="D MMM YYYY" autofocus >
```

that is modified with [Combodate](https://vitalets.github.io/combodate/).

```
// Get Current Year with js (implements)
$('#date_xs').combodate({
  minYear:2016
});
```

However, the client side validation doesn't work properly, and no error message is returned.

In Js:

```
  $("form[name='form-receipt']").validate({
  rules: {
    date:{
      required: true
    },
},
messages: {
    date: {
      required: "Custom error mex",
    },
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Is there anyone who has encountered the same problem?

Comment: `comboDate`  plugin hides the input... validation engine works with visible elements I guess...

Answer (score 0):

yes @Marcos Pérez Gude you are right so add ignore: [], in your validate function and it's working fine [example link here](http://jsfiddle.net/5m6gG/439/)

```
$("#dateForm").validate({
 ignore: [],
 rules: {
   date: {
     required:true
   },
   name:{
     required:true
   }
 }
```

});